# PHPStan errors on Laravel Model relationships, any solutions?

Tags: laravel, phpstan

PHPStan has found hundreds of errors in the Laravel project. Mostly, Access to an undefined property Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::$id.
for constructs like

```
$project_id = $checkpoint->project->id;
```

Does PHPStan not understand the relationships between Laravel models? (larastan is also installed)

Do I really need to rewrite everything to

```
$project_id = $checkpoint->project->id ?? null;
```

(then PHPStan doesn't complain).

I tried to overcome this error through PHPDoc, but even more changes would have to be made to the code here.

Comment: Using the [ide helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) might work for you (it's called "IDE" helper but it auto-generates PHPDoc so PHPStan should be able to read that as well).

Answer (score 0):

create MyModel class extending base Model class and use it for your inheritance.
In this class you can typehint properties that commonly used in your tables like "it", "created_at"...